# python error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists in a dict and I am trying to splice the elements into a string

Here is my Python code:

```
a = {'A': {'A.A': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 'A.B': [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]}}

for i in range(len(a['A']['A.A'])):
    for j in range(len(a['A']['A.B'])):
        name = str(a['A']['A.A'][i]) + '+' + str(['A']['A.B'][j])
        print(name)
```

and I got this error:

```
  File "G:\Temp\temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    name=str(a['A']['A.A'][i])+'+'+str(['A']['A.B'][j])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I don't understand why i and j are str, not int.

How can this work?

Comment: `str(['A']['A.B'][j])` -> `str(a['A']['A.B'][j])`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `a`:

```
a=dict()
a={'A':{'A.A':[1.0,2.0,3.0],'A.B':[4.0,5.0,6.0]}}
for i in range(len(a['A']['A.A'])):
    for j in range(len(a['A']['A.B'])):
        # in the following line you had ['A']['A.B'][j]
        # instead of a['A']['A.B'][j]
        name=str(a['A']['A.A'][i])+'+'+str(a['A']['A.B'][j])
        print(name)
```

In your code, `['A']['A.B']` is trying to index a list (`['A']`) with a string, and it expects integers as indeces.

Comment: sorry for my stupid mistake. now it works well.

Comment: @Thaumaturge_void, no problem. Could you please validate my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

name=str(a['A']['A.A'][i])+'+'+str(**a**['A']['A.B'][j]), you omit **a** before `['A']['A.B'][j]`

Comment: sorry for my stupid mistake. now it works well.

Answer (score -1):

`i` and `j` aren't strings. But `'A.B'` is when you are trying to do `['A']['A.B']`.